# Rails - Post model/User association view returning user object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my post index view it is showing "#" as the user, when trying post.user.email it gives me an error, when using @post.user.email on the single view page however it gives me the correct email.

I believe this means I have the association wrong?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_commentable


end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
  has_many :posts, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

end

t.references :user, index: true
```

The last line of code is what I used in the post migration, I think that's where I goofed maybe? Should it be the :user_id?

Sorry, forgot to paste in what it is showing

```
 #<User:0x007fa7845b9310>
```

Is what it is giving me when it should be an email address.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end


<% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.user %></td>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.content %></td>
        <td><%= post.subject %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you add your Posts Controller for the index action code.
If you're trying to reference variables in the view page they need to begin with an '@'.
Such '@' beginning variables are defined in the controller and made accessible to the views. So if you define `@post` in the controller it will be accessible in the view, but if you just define `post` it will only be accessible in the controller and not the view.

Comment: @steve I added both the post#index and the view snippet.

Comment: `#<User:0x007fa7845b9310>` is what a user object looks like. So if `post.user` returns `#<User:0x007fa7845b9310>` then you know that the post belongs to a user, which is good.

What exactley is the error you are getting when you try `<td><%= post.user.email %></td> in that `each` block?

Comment: One problem is that the numbers change on each page refresh which isn't good... posts#show does show the proper association and allows me to call post.user.email

Comment: Are you getting an error that something like "Undefined method email for Nil class"?

Comment: I am. Sorry I thought I put that in there but I see now that I didn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49783/discussion-between-patrick-cauley-and-steve)

Answer (score 0):

`<%= post.user %>` will only output the `user` object

If your tables & associations are set up correctly, you'll need to do call the user details specifically, like this:

```
<%= post.user.created_at %>
```

Since you're receiving errors from this, there are several issues you may have:

> 1. Your association (& schemas) could be incorrect
> 2. Your `User` object could be malformed
> 3. There could be an issue somewhere else in your code

---

**Debug**

I'd highly recommend doing this in your `index` view:

```
<%= debug @post.user %>
```

This will output the entire `user` object, where you'll be able to identify the attributes it has, allowing you to get a better view of what it's coming back with. After that, post the returned data & we'll be in a better position to help

Comment: Thanks, in case anyone else has a similar problem I found the solution with help from the commenter above, steve. I had a post without an associated user which was causing the nilClass to be a problem.